# How do i get this program to stop printing the same number 3 times?

Tags: java, for-loop

My code keeps outputing everything 3 times instead of once. My goal is to get 3 number to print on the same line then move the only problem is instead of printing 3 different variable its printing 3 times the same 1 and moving to next line.

```
int counter=0;
    do {    
    for(int c= a; c <= b; c++){
        if (c % 3 ==0);
        System.out.print("");
        counter++;
        int counte = 0;
    
        for (int i = 0 ; i <3 ; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3 ; j++) {
                System.out.print (c);
                System.out.print (" "); // I think it is best to have spaces between the numbers
              
            }
            //after printing 10 numbers, go to a new                                   line
             System.out.println ();
           }
        
            
          }
    

          }while(counter<3);
```

Answer (score 0):

let's look at this part of the code:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 3 ; j++) {
    System.out.print (c);
    System.out.print (" ");              
}
```

you are iterating 3 times and each time you are printing the value of c.
inside that loop you are not changing the value of c so it makes sense that it would print the same value 3 times.
is "c" the variable you intended to print?
i can't understand whats the goal of this code (what are you intending to print?) so i can't really advise you on how to fix it, but what i mentioned above would be a good starting point.

i highly suggest you not to name your variable "a, b, c" etc.. because it makes the code extremely hard to understand, maintain and fix.

here are other things that might be interrupting:

1. your if clause is useless as you don't perform any action related to it (you just write an "if clause" then ; and continue you code"

2.the print after the if clause is also quite redundant because you are printing nothing at all

3. you aren't using the "counte" variable, is this a mistake?

i believe that if you'll organize the code a little bit you'll find it quite easy to spot your mistake and fix your code. good luck :)